# Switching table partition into temporary table

Tags: partitioning, temporary-tables, sql-server-2022

I'm trying to switch a table partition into a temporary table with the following query:

```sql
create partition function [PFCT_T](datetime2) as range right for values ()
create partition scheme [PSCH_T] as partition [PFCT_T] all to ([primary])
    
create table T(A1 datetime2 not null, A2 int not null) on [PSCH_T](A1)
create clustered columnstore index [CIX_T] on dbo.T
    
insert into T(A1, A2) values ('2024-01-01 00:00:00', 1)
    
select top 0 * into #T from T
create clustered columnstore index [CIX_#T] on #T
    
alter table T switch partition 1 to #T
--Results in:
--Msg 608, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
--No catalog entry found for partition ID 5620492390548766720 in database 23. The metadata is inconsistent. Run DBCC CHECKDB to check for a metadata corruption.
```

Is it not possible to switch a partition into a temporary table (it works with normal Tables) or did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're executing the script in a user database. Temp tables are created in the tempdb system database and one cannot use `SWITCH` to move data between tables in different databases.

The script will work if you simply add `USE tempdb;` to the beginning of the script but I suspect your intent is to create the permanent objects in a user database. You'll need to use a permanent table instead of a temp table for the `SWITCH` in that case.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Yeah I'll just use a normal table then.

Comment: FWIW all indexes/heaps need to be the same, and need to be in the same filegroup(s).